# `let` expressions in this position are unstable

Tags: string, rust

I want to iterate over two strings in Rust. I read that it's not efficient to use indexes (`nth()` method). Thats why I am using iterators

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("abacde");
    let s2 = String::from("123456");
    let mut iter1 = s1.chars();
    let mut iter2 = s2.chars();

    while let Some(ch1) = iter1.next() && let Some(ch2) = iter2.next(){
        println!("{:?}", ch1);
    }
}
```

I have an error

> error[E0658]: `let` expressions in this position are unstable

How to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve your actual problem you can iterate over 2 iterators in lockstep with `zip`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("abacde");
    let s2 = String::from("123456");

    for (ch1, ch2) in s1.chars().zip(s2.chars()){
        println!("{ch1} {ch2}");
    }
}
```

To answer your question:
`let` chains, as multiple let assignments within a `while` or `if` are called are unstable. All unstable features require a nightly compiler to use. You'll also need to enable the [`let_chains` feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53667) for the specific syntax in your question.

```rust
#![feature(let_chains)] // added at the top of your code
```

in fact when you're using a nightly compiler it will tell you to do so:

```
error[E0658]: `let` expressions in this position are unstable
 --> src/main.rs:7:11
  |
7 |     while let Some(ch1) = iter1.next() && let Some(ch2) = iter2.next(){
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: see issue #53667 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53667> for more information
  = help: add `#![feature(let_chains)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a *tuple* and *destructure*.

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("abacde");
    let s2 = String::from("123456");
    let mut iter1 = s1.chars();
    let mut iter2 = s2.chars();

    while let (Some(ch1), Some(ch2)) = (iter1.next(),iter2.next()) {
        println!("{:?} {:?}", ch1, ch2);
    }
    println!("done");
}
```

[rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=fn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+s1+%3D+String%3A%3Afrom%28%22abacde%22%29%3B%0A++++let+s2+%3D+String%3A%3Afrom%28%22123456%22%29%3B%0A++++let+mut+iter1+%3D+s1.chars%28%29%3B%0A++++let+mut+iter2+%3D+s2.chars%28%29%3B%0A%0A++++while+let+%28Some%28ch1%29%2C+Some%28ch2%29%29+%3D+%28iter1.next%28%29%2C+iter2.next%28%29%29+%7B%0A++++++++println%21%28%22%7B%3A%3F%7D+%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C+ch1%2C+ch2%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++println%21%28%22done%22%29%3B%0A%7D%0A)